# Browser sniffing for user's history - on it's way out?

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser

Will Firefox 4, Chrome 6 and IE9 secure this security hole where user history can be accessed with js?

http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2008/02/browser-history-sniff.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 4 beta already has this fixed, I haven't seen any plans to fix this for other browsers

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

edit:
Looks like chrome 6 has this fixed too (tested with chrome unstable)

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40312

Comment: that't good to hear. i wonder if google will start to penalise

Answer (score 1):

This ten year old exploit has now been pretty much plugged as of April 2011 in both latest versions FF4 and IE9 respectively.

Javascript no longer has direct access to the pseudo CSS classes such as :visited that were at the core of the problem. Some folk are hinting that a workaround may be achievable via class inheritence or HTML5 canvas but no POC code has appeared as of yet.